# list of data.table: filter by variable

Tags: r, list, data.table

I have a list of data.tables

```
library(data.table); set.seed(42)
l <- list(data.table(id=1:5, x=rnorm(5)), data.table(id=1:5, x=rnorm(5)))

> l
[[1]]
   id          x
1:  1  1.3709584
2:  2 -0.5646982
3:  3  0.3631284
4:  4  0.6328626
5:  5  0.4042683

[[2]]
   id           x
1:  1 -0.10612452
2:  2  1.51152200
3:  3 -0.09465904
4:  4  2.01842371
5:  5 -0.06271410
```

each of which with the same IDs.

I would like to extract from each element only ID 3, but would not know how this works. I thought of `lapply(l, )` but don't know how to continue. Is there a standin-variable for each list element, say `xx`, so I could use `lapply(l,subset(xx, id==3))`?

Comment: This works `lapply(l,function(t) t[which(t$id ==3),] )`. For every element of your list (`t`)  you need to extract the rows that have an `id == 3` . Also `subset` should work.

Comment: I see! In fact `lapply(l,function(t) t[id==3])` also works! What exactly does  `function(t) ...` do? I keep seeing this "trick" but would never have guessed this could be a solution here. I understand it introduces the "handle" I was looking for but I don't quite understand what it does in general.

Comment: Apply the function `t[which(t$id ==3),] ` (or `t[id==3]`) to every values of `t`. It is the same as doing `for(t in l){print(t[id==3])}`

Comment: It's an [anonymous function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function), which allows you to pass something more complicated to `lapply` than single parameter functions.

Comment: Thanks! I think I am getting the hang of it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `data.table` subsetting (that should be faster):

```
lapply(l, "[", id == 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `subset` without an anonymous call in this case by doing

```
lapply(l, subset, id == 3)

#[[1]]
#   id         x
#1:  3 0.3631284

#[[2]]
#   id           x
#1:  3 -0.09465904
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is `map` from `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
map(l, ~ .x %>%
               filter(id == 3))
```